# Using htaccess regex with range to redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

This is my .htaccess regex:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/news/([0-9][0-9][0-9])?/16$ /index.php/news/$1/16 [L,R=301]
```

That works. But, I need the range 0-1879 to redirect to `/index.php/news/$1/16` and more than 1879 to redirect to  `http://otherdomain/index.php/news/$1/16`.

Answer (score 0):

**You shouldn't do this, but...**

Here's how you match 0-1879:

```
[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|1[0-7][0-9]{2}|18[0-6][0-9]|187[0-9]
```

Here's how you match 1880-infinity

```
18[8-9][0-9]|19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4}
```

<sub>Note: with the alternation, you'll need to wrap these in a group `()` to properly nest the logic.</sub>

---

**Instead I recommend...**

Just match 0+ digits and redirect to the other domain. If the number is 0-1879 (in your backend language, controller, etc.), then redirect them back to the original domain. Or figure out how to get the old news migrated over to the other domain, if your doing what I think you're doing.